# Rename the label names in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, lambda

I have a multiclass dataframe. The labels in the dataframe (shown in array) are like this:

```
[label:A,label:B,label:C,label:D,label:E,label:F,label:G,label:H,label:I]
```

How can I convert all of them into format:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? There is `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: No multi-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('label:', '', regex=True)
```

Or if same values in first level of `MulltiIndex`:

```
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```